# Down voting on a question that shouldn't be there

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-questions

I have a question with -5 votes it had -3 and I had no use for the question because the answer don't help me, but the problem was overcome. I tried to delete it but it wasn't going away so I changed the 1500 words to random letters and hoping the short paragraph would able able to get deleted but now I'm loosing reputation on a thing I can't get rid of! What shall I do???? Ugh :/

Comment: Deleting questions just because they don't come out the way you want will eventually get you question banned. Take the time to write good answerable questions and that won't happen.

Answer (score 5):

## Improve your question.

[That thing](https://askubuntu.com/q/371500/169736) is just a bunch of scrambled words impossible to understand. Some hero, read your question and provided an answer. Others found that his heroic act should be recompensed and upvoted the answer. You can't ask someone to delete their answer just because it wasn't helpful to you. You should edit your question and provide the results of what the answer suggested, if it didn't work, what changed, **details**.

[Lets analyze your question like Jack the ripper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNagK.png):

1. **Make a descriptive title!** Your title doesn't give the slightness idea what your problem is about. You are not in a conversation, you are asking a question. Also, do not ask for "ASAPness". We are volunteers, we do not have a *obligation to help* but want to help. You can't put pressure on us.
2. Please, **do not write all in CAPS nor fill your question of Smilies.** You wouldn't make your boss read a document like that, don't make us read it either.
3. **[Learn how to ask a good question.](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask)** Seriously, all the reasons for each of those downvotes are there. When writing, you must make sure that your words are easy to digest by the people that will be reading (and possible answering) your question. You should read your own question and see if **YOU** can answer it yourself.

**Can you understand your own question?** No? Edit! Improve! but DO SOMETHING! We already have shown you the ropes, beyond that you must put of your own effort and show us that you indeed improved.

Comment: No, I asked them to delete the answer because I trying to delete the question, someone told me I can't delete a question that has an answer

Comment: Instead of deleting your question, **improve it**. That's what we are asking. That's what [Fossfreedom comment is asking you](http://askubuntu.com/questions/371500/cannot-boot-computer-help-please#comment478712_371500), **just improve**.

Comment: Wow u guys would down grade my question. You guys are so rude!!!

Comment: We haven't "downgrading" anything. Please, read the [help] and see how things works here.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately as the system works you may not be able to delete your question:

- [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

This may be the case here. Also note that a question put "on hold" can only be deleted by the community after a period of 48 hours:

- [What is a "closed" or “on hold” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question)

For the community to be able to delete a post it needs to have downvotes. Downvoted posts may also under some circumstances be automatically deleted by the system (see above for details). So technically it does make sense that a question was downvoted to get it deleted.

However I feel it is overkill to further downvote a close question if it already had sufficient downvotes. This is even more so as a user may not be able to self-delete their post. They may get into a **downvote trap** with no other choice than flagging the post for moderator attention. Moderators will be able to delete a post immediately.

Editing may not always be an option, even less so when the user saw that indeed their post was useless.

Comment: Takkat, I do not agree, the user had a valid question, and asked [*another* question about the same problem](http://askubuntu.com/q/373558/169736). He apparently just wanted to get rid of the DV of his bad question.. If that's the case, why not just improve the other question?

Comment: @Braiam: fair enough, in this case this yould indeed be the way to go. Other cases may be different. People may come here for advice after they experienced the downvote trap (just imagine a case where somebody get hundreds of downvotes but the system does not let them delete their question).